# standard container swap overloads

Tags: c++, c++11

The standard library containers don't have a `swap` overload
for rvalue reference. 
Is this an oversight, or is there
a rational behind it?

In addition to

```
void map::swap( map& );
```

there could be a

```
void map::swap( map&& );
```

because stealing the guts of a temporary should not be a problem?

Comment: That's just move assignment?

Comment: You can swap the other way: `f().swap(x)`

Comment: swapping 2 rvalues probably means you're doing it wrong...

Comment: @T.C. : doh, did not think of that

Comment: @M.M : I don't follow

Answer (score -2):

I don't think they can take rvalue-reference.

`swap` modifies both arguments, and since rvalue is kind of 'read only' it looks bad to me.

`copy_from( from_container&& )` may take ravlue-reference

Comment: "Rvalue" has nothing to do at all with "read-only". In fact, almost all of the improvements of C++11 are based precisely on the idea of mutating rvalues. The correct statement is that "rvalue" is a kind of "not aliased".